# Using Winrar's rar.exe with commandline interface to archive sub folders

Tags: windows, backup, batch, archiving, rar

I was hoping someone might be able to answer this. I've seen similar questions, but none specific to my question.

Using rar.exe in a batch file under Windows 8.1 PRO I want to archive a set of sub folders, but not all sub folders under the root directory.

For example...

I'm running a program that makes sub folders as needed starting with the word cloud. Today there might be three sub folders cloud1, cloud2, cloud3. tomorrow depending on what happened within the program there may be additional sub folders cloud4, cloud5, etc...

The point above is that there isn't a static number or sub folders that need to be archived. There can be more tomorrow than today and this batch file will be required to archive all cloud* sub folders when the batch file is executed once per day.

So, in my root folder you have the following sub folders.

bin

cloud1

cloud2

cloud_storage_alpha

summary

xraid

My batch file will run once a day at 4AM, inside this batch file I need the command line for rar.exe to archive all sub folders that begin with the word cloud (in this example it would be cloud1, cloud2, cloud_storage_alpha) and to archive all data (files and further sub folders) found within the cloud* sub folders. Also, please remember today it may be cloud1, cloud2, cloud_storage_alpha, but tomorrow there might be new cloud* sub folders that will need to be backed up along with the pre-existing cloud* sub folders.

Can this be done?

If not, is there a way via robocopy or some other windows command to copy all the sub folders that begin with the word cloud to a separate sub folder called backup. If so, then I can have rar.exe just backup all the contents of the sub folder backup. This will accomplish the same thing, except it only requires two programs robocopy(or similar) and rar.exe where the first example would all be done in rar.exe.

If anyone can help me, I'd truly appreciate it.

Thanks,
John

PS: Is there a way to append a date to the end of the rar archive file? 
Ex: Lets say today 11/13/2015 the cloud sub folders were archived to a file called backup.rar. Is there a way to have the archive backup.rar be actually saved as backup11-13-15.rar or similar?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: With rar comes a document that describes how to do this... Possibly also available at rarlabs.com

Comment: This is a rather long posting, and my guess is that most people won't bother to read all of it. I suggest that you break down your project into parts, work out the parts you can, and ask about the others individually. That will result in several questions and answers that others will find useful, instead of one big over-specialized posting that only helps you (and probably not even that).

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple batch task. 
Refer to page :
http://comptb.cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/
It will help you to use winrar command line, specially multiple switches portion is useful for you.